# Angular 15 Routing with @ in URL

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

Quick Question: Is it possible to route something like domain.com/@Username? The @ is **not** part of the username itself.

I already tried `{ path: "@:username", component: UserComponent }` but this doesn't seem to work.

`{ path: "@/:username", component: UserComponent }` would work but looks pretty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer in the angular docs for [routing with url matcher](https://angular.io/guide/routing-with-urlmatcher#configure-your-routes-for-your-application).

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        matcher: (url) => {
          if (url.length === 1 && url[0].path.match(/^@.+$/gm)) {   
            return {
              consumed: url
              posParams: {
                username: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.slice(1), {}),
              },
            };
          }

          return null;
        },
        component: UserComponent,
    },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the "@" symbol as "%40" in the URL. So, to achieve the desired routing pattern of domain.com/@Username, you can use the following route configuration:

```
{ path: "%40:username", component: UserComponent }
```

Edit:

Ensure that you have defined the route correctly in your routing module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '%40:username', component: UserComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Make sure you are using the correct router outlet in your template file. For example, if you want to render the UserComponent in the main router outlet, your template should have a router-outlet element.

Double-check that you are navigating to the correct URL format. For instance, if you're using routerLink in your template to navigate to the user component, make sure it is encoded properly:

```
<a [routerLink]="['%40', 'Username']">Go to User</a>
```

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work. `{ path: "%40/:username", component: UserComponent }` didn't work either. Is there anything else that needs to be taken into account? I'm use Angular 15 by the way

Comment: Your edit still doesn't work! The link `<a [routerLink]="['%40', 'Username']">Go to User</a>` will route to /@/Username what exactly is, which is what I don't want like i wrote above. 

%40 in the path is still not working, but @ does